# Getting Docker Container Id in Makefile to use in another command

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a rule in my Makefile.  Within this rule I need to manipulate some docker specific things so I need to get the id of the container in a portable way.  In addition, I am using Docker Compose. Here is what I have that doesn't work.

```
a-rule: some deps
    $(shell uuid="$(docker-compose ps -q myService)" docker cp "$$uuid":/a/b/c .)
```

I receive no errors or output, but I do not get a successful execution.

My goal is to get the uuid of the container that myService is running in and then use that uuid to copy a file from the container to my docker host.

edit:
the following works, but I'm still wondering if its possible to do inline variable settings

```
uuid=$(shell docker-compose ps -q myService)
a-rule: some deps
    docker cp "$(uuid)":/a/b/c .
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and realised that makefiles take output from shell variables with the use of `$$`. So I tried that and this should work for you:

```
a-rule: some deps
    uuid=$$(docker-compose ps -q myService);\ 
    docker cp "$$uuid":/a/b/c .
```

Bit late to the party but I hope this helps someone.